# Properly implement REMOTE_USER-like thing for ssh

Tags: ssh, authentication, remote, users

I'd like to know how to make the remote user name available in an ssh session on my server. So when `joe@host1` logs in as `commonuser@server1`, the scripts running on `server1` running as `commonuser` will know that the person running them is actually `joe`.

1. I tried `SendEnv` / `AcceptEnv` without luck. I even looked at SSH debug output and it looked like the environment variable was sent, but when I do

   `echo $REMOTE_USER`

   I see empty string.
2. I would also like this to be working even if `joe` is less cooperative, for example when he refuses to set the `REMOTE_USER` variable.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? It would seem to be more reasonable to simply let joe log in as joe, and handle commonalities with things like groups.

Comment: There is no way to do this where you can actually trust that the information is authentic. Other than using unique ssh keys for each remote user, but then again the users can change their own keys... Don't use shared accounts, even on jumpboxes.

Comment: @Spooler: No, it won't work. We have hosts where we do not want to have multiple users. These are actually on-board computers for robots. This does not have to be extremely secure, the point is to prevent accidental cross-user operations (like user joe commits a quickfix into git as the common user, or in the name some other user.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to connect multiple remote persons to the same local user account, you should use SSH keys and have each user use their own key.

This allows you to identify the key used to login (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15575/1016) for more details). Without keys, you can't identify the remote user at all.

If you set `PermitUserEnvironment=yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you then can also force an environment variable in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file like so:

```
cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

environment="REMOTE_USER=joe@remote1" ssh-dss AAAAB3Nza......
```

(See `man sshd` for more information about authorized_keys and `man sshd_config`).